# how can I do the button that is appears when screen size smaller

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I want a button appears when screen size is smaller. How can I do?

I work with asp.net.

Comment: Did you google? because then you would find something usefull like https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I googled very much. But I don't find useful anything

Comment: Use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: @Andersen, I have found your response but this isn't that I want

Comment: @fico Do you want to do it in the code behind?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple example how you can use [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

**UPDATE:** Here you have a full and up to date exmplenation for [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

You need to resize the window to 600px or less so that you can see the button.

```css
button {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  button {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<button>Test</button>

<p>Resize the browser window. When the width of this document is 600 pixels or less, the button is visible, otherwise not".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries